# Format outputting time in the Yii2

Tags: yii2

```
\Yii::$app->formatter->asDuration($timePeriod)
```

this code gets from database data, 15 days, 9 hours, 48 minutes, 3 seconds ago I get. How to format this code? To cut days and seconds, what method will help?

Comment: What exactly is the result you expect from cutting days and seconds? Converting that "15 days, 9 hours, 48 minutes, 3 seconds ago" to something like "9 hours, 48 minutes ago"?

Comment: yes, I definitely do not want to show users such long string

Comment: Well, i can understand cutting out seconds. I would probably understand cutting out minutes if the difference is more than few hours. But there is huge difference in meaning between "15 days, 9 hours" and "9 hours", right?

Comment: yes, you are right, but at least some part i need to remove